# Not able to login to my web application after I configured Spring security 3.1.4 version

Tags: spring, filter, spring-security

I cannot access the login page of my application. While trying to access the application its showing the below error message in sysout. Please tell me where I went wrong.

**Sysout:**

.....config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected Anonymous access to the login page doesn't appear to be enabled. This is almost certainly an error. Please check your configuration allows unauthenticated access to the configured login page. (Simulated access was rejected: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied)

This behavior happened after I configured a spring security configuration file in which I've the below data.

Spring security config xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login-page.jsp" access="permitALl" 
requires-channel="any"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login-page.jsp" default-target-url="/homePage.spr"
        always-use-default-target='true' 
        authentication-failure-url="/accessDeniedPage.jsp" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout-page.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

</http>
```

Comment: That is a warning not an error. To remove this warning add the anonymous authentication filter (add the <anonymous /> tag.

Comment: If that's not an error and just a warning my application shouls get loaded with the 'login-page.jsp'. But it's not happening. I think I'm missing something here so only my app hits a 'cannot display webpage' message!!

Comment: The fact that your page cannot be loaded has nothing to do with the warning. Enable debug logging and see why it is failing. Also make sure that `/login-page.jsp` is in the root of your web application and not a view resolved by spring.